# Why is it wrong to bind a function to an object using a closure?

Tags: python

I want for the bound function to have access to `a`.  However, I have read that this approach is wrong.  Why is it wrong? And, please provide an example of the recommended approach.

```
class Some(object):

    a = 1

    def __init__(self, function):

        self.function = function(self)

    def method(self):

        print(self.a)


def function(self):

    def inner():

        print(self.a)

    return inner

thing = Some(function)

thing.function()
```

Comment: Try like that `self.a = 1`

Comment: `self` outside of a class? `f`, `f0`, `f1`? This code is incredibly hard to follow, maybe that's why you shouldn't do it this way ...

Comment: "I have read that this approach is wrong" => where ? If someone states that this is wrong then he surely explains why...

Comment: That's the purpose of the question.  I want to know why it is wrong.

Comment: And it's why I ask you where you "have read" this.

Comment: @Aemyl `self` is just a name, there's absolutely nothing magical about it, and where you define a function (within a class or outside a class) is actually totally irrelevant, it's still a function. What makes it a method is not where is defined but the fact that it's resolved as an attribute of a class.  All this is explained here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know that `self` isn't a reserved keyword in python but using it outside of a class is just bad coding style

Comment: @Aemyl "bad coding style" ??? chapter and verse, please ? If your function is to be used as a method, naming the first argument `self` (instead of ` obj` or `instance` or whatever) makes the intention clearer, so I fail to see how this could be "bad coding style", quite on the contrary.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers when I see `def f(self):`, I expect it to be a method of a class rather than a top-level function. While using `self` makes clearer what the function expects, it sets this function itself into another context. Especially because `self` is usually not passed explicitly to a function, `obj` or `instance` would be a much better fit here

Comment: @Aemyl that's your own personal opinion. I respect it as such, but it doesn't make it "bad coding style". And once again, understand that what makes a function a method is not where it's defined but how it's looked up, so as far as I'm concerned the fact that it's "a top level function" is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Aemyl The abstract identifier names were to emphasize the intent of the question.  I changed it.  Is it still hard for you to follow?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It's been my experience that assertion without explanation is a pretty common behavior amongst the species.  The strawman specimen provided here in the comments is a typical example that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you read that this approach was wrong, but there's certainly an  explanation with this statement so perhaps you should post the link ?

But anyway: if the point is to add per-instances methods, there's already a builtin way to do so. [As explained here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod), python functions implement the descriptor protocol so `func.__get__(obj, type(obj))` will return a bound method (which is itself a callable wrapper over the function, instance and class). IOW, all you have to do to turn a function into a method bound to an instance is to manually invoke the descriptor protocol:

```
class Other(object):
    a = 1

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func.__get__(self, type(self))


def f(self):
    return self.a

o = Other(f)
print("o.func :", o.func())
```

Your function of course needs to take the instance as first argument...

If you want to add a method to the class itself, it's even simpler, you just have to bind the function to the class and the attribute resolution (`object.__getattribute__()`) will invoke the descriptor protocol itself.

So whether your solution is "wrong" or not depends on how you define "wrong". At least it's technically legal, it works, and there's no obvious drawback (or at least I don't see any) - but it's not the "obvious" solution ([the definition of "obvious" may vary](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) though)